# Get latest response from the service angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a requirement like.

There are more than 15000 records of users. An i want to search them by name typing in text box.

[image]

Now where someone types xyz and instantly abc by removing the previous one. so, some times what happens it bind the result of the last response not the latest response data. Which strategy should i follow? please help. Is there any way to stop the previous response?

**Using :- Angular 6 and nodejs with my sql.**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you need to used rxjs with the last() method to get your last updated data. more you can find here.. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/last.html and also you can go with some strategy where you clear the temp array before search occur.

Comment: https://blog.strongbrew.io/building-a-safe-autocomplete-operator-with-rxjs/

Answer (score 1):

`Unsubscribe` the previous subscription response:

```
this.allRecords.unsubscribe();
this.allRecords=this.expService.getList(queryString).subscribe();
```

Comment: better use async pipe (so you need fight with subscribe/unsubscribe)